# Add minutes to strtotime

Tags: php, strtotime

If i have a varible

```
// in minutes
$min = 40;
```

And i want to add it to a strotime formatted time

```
$strtTime = $strtotime('now') + $min;
```

whats the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can do this:

```
strtotime("+{$min} minutes");
```

Comment: The second parameter should be an integer (i.e. a Unix timestamp). Only the first parameter can be a time string.

Answer (score 10):

There's not much to it:

```
echo strtotime("+40 minutes");
```

[See it in action](http://3v4l.org/je3Wb)

Answer (score 3):

Well, look at the [documentation](http://php.net/strtotime#refsect1-function.strtotime-examples). It tells you how to use the function.

```
$future = strtotime('+40 minutes');
```

You can also be a little more concrete and include where to start from.

```
$future = strtotime('now + 40 minutes');
```

While the above is a lot easier you could also do it manually. It just involves some basic arithmetic:

```
$now     = time(); // Seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00
$minutes = 40;
$seconds = ($minutes * 60); // 2400 seconds
$future  = ($now + $seconds);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$min = 40;
```

And i want to add it to a strotime formatted time

```
$strtTime = strtotime("+".$min." minutes", strtotime('now'));//eg +40 minutes
```